# Inverse Proportion on a graph

Tags: arithmetic

The force of attraction(F newtons) between two magnets is inversely proportional to the square of the distance , d centimetres , between the magnets .

Sketch a graph to show relationship between force and distance on both axis that begins with 0. Y axis is the Force , X axis is the distance .

Can I get help on how the shape of this graph should look like ? My graph looks something like this

[image]

Comment: It should look like a parabola

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the fact that the force is "inversely proportional to the square of the distance" is

$F = \frac{k}{d^2}$

where k is some arbitrary constant. It means as the *square* of the distance changes, the force will change "inversely" (hence the division by $r^2$ instead of multiplication by $r^2$).

So the graph would look like:

[image: Graph]

Where the x-axis is distance and the y-axis is force between the magnets.